# java sort hashtable with object value by the objecs string parameter

Tags: java, hashtable

I have an hashable that contains a string key , and a class object value:

```
Hashtable<String,myclass>m_class_table = new Hashtable<String,myclass>();
```

inside 'myclass' I have a String field value,

I need to sort my hashtable according to this string value.

I can't just sort it by the hashtable values beacuse it is an object..

How can this be done?

Thank's In Advance.

Comment: Hashtables can't be sorted...it's against the contract of the class.  Have a look at TreeMap instead.

Comment: @stevevls: I can sort it by putting the keyset inside an arraylist and then put it inside a collection and sort it..

Comment: The string-keys, are they equivalent to the string field of the myclass-object which it points at?

Comment: That gives you a new sorted collection. It doesn't sort the HashTable itself. Perhaps you need to reword your question a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slight variation on aioobe's answer: I'd create a List of the Map entries and sort that list. That way you still have access to the complete map entries.

```
Map<String, MyClass> map = new HashMap<String, MyClass>();
// add some entries

List<Entry<String,MyClass>> entryList = 
     new ArrayList<Entry<String,MyClass>>(map.entrySet());
Collections.sort(entryList, new Comparator<Entry<String,MyClass>>() {
    public int compare(
        Entry<String, MyClass> first, Entry<String, MyClass> second) {
            return first.getValue().getFoo()
                        .compareTo(second.getValue().getFoo());
    }
});
```

Comment: thank's to the answers I got - I found this solution and it works greate! http://www.coderanch.com/t/478708/java/java/comparator-example-needed

Answer (score 2):

> ***I need to sort my hashtable according to this string value.***

A hashtable is not a sorted data structure.

You can use some [`SortedMap`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html), such as a [`TreeMap`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) but those data structures sorts on the keys, so that will only work if the key equals the string-field of the object pointed to.

> ***I can't just sort it by the hashtable values beacuse it is an object..***

You need to provide a `Comparator<myclass>`, or, let `myclass` implement the `Comparable` interface.

Depending on how you iterate over the hash-table, you could perhaps do like this:

```
List<myclass> myObjects = new ArrayList<myclass>(m_class_table.values());
Collections.sort(myObjects, new Comparator<myclass>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(myclass o1, myclass o2) {
        o1.stringField.compareTo(o2.stringField);
    }
});
```

and then iterate over the `myObjects` list. (Elements in a `List` are ordered.)

Comment: thank's to the answers I got - I found this solution and it works greate! http://www.coderanch.com/t/478708/java/java/comparator-example-needed